# Spine.js - How do you unbind a specific event handler from a model instance using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, spine.js

It's pretty easy to unbind specific event handlers from model classes, but it seems the only way to unbind an event handler from an instance of a model is to unbind ALL event handlers attached to that instance using `unbind()` (takes no arguments).

Is there an equivalent to Model class' `unbind([eventName, function])` function for model instances, or is there another better way to unbind specific handlers without unbinding them all?

I've looked through the [Spine.js documentation](http://spinejs.com/api/models) but no luck so far. Adding arguments to the `unbind()` function has no effect - it just ignores them and unbinds all anyway.

Comment: never worked with the Spine, might be a bug. can you post some code to make sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end we switched to a more suitable framework for our needs, [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org). Maintenance on the [Spine.js GitHub repository](https://github.com/maccman/spine) seems to have ground to a halt in September last year and, though Spine supports use with JavaScript, the documentation for it is pretty poor.

If anyone can provide a working solution to the original problem I'll still accept it for the benefit of anyone else who stumbles across this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this specifically answers your question but might get you to what you are going for.

Spine has a not so documented .one() event

from the source:

```
one: (ev, callback) ->
  @bind ev, ->
    @unbind(ev, arguments.callee)
    callback.apply(this, arguments)
```

So it basically does the unbind for you behind the scenes, but it doesn't use a Model unbind which actually just triggers 'unbind'.

```
unbind: (ev, callback) ->
  unless ev
    @_callbacks = {}
    return this

  list = @_callbacks?[ev]
  return this unless list

  unless callback
    delete @_callbacks[ev]
    return this

  for cb, i in list when cb is callback
    list = list.slice()
    list.splice(i, 1)
    @_callbacks[ev] = list
    break
  this
```

vs.

```
  unbind: ->
    @trigger('unbind')
```

We use @item.one in a few places and have found it works okay.

example use:

```
@item.one 'awaitingPermit', (item) =>
  @navigate('/document', item.id, 'show')
```

**update:**
We have worked on some solutions to this missing feature in Spine.js. see this issue thread https://github.com/spine/spine/issues/418

Comment: Not quite what we're looking for since each handler could be called multiple times before being unbound, plus we're not using CoffeeScript.